# İ can't pull data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I want to pull data using JavaScript and show it in console. I don't know what I did wrong.

main.js

```
// ADD TO CART
$("#addToCartBtn").on('click',function(){
  var _qty=$("#productQty").val();
  var _productId=$(".product-id").val();
  var _productName=$(".product-name").val();
  console.log(_productId,_productName,_qty);
});
```

I am using django framework to write backend

detail.html

```
<div class="product-btns">
    <div class="qty-input">
        <span class="text-uppercase">Ədəd: </span>
        <input class="input" type="number" value="1" id="productQty">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="{{product.id}}">
    <input type="hidden" class="product-name" value="{{product.name}}">
    <button class="primary-btn add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" id="addToCartBtn"></i> Səbətə at</button>
</div>
```

Comment: um, your click event is tied only to the icon. Seems a bit weird. Why is the id not on the button?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the element that has `id="addToCartBtn"` is not really the button but the `<i>` element - which has no content and therefore no width. So it is never clickable.

Comment: I gave the id to the button but it still didn't work

Comment: Just to be sure, did you also remove the id from `<i>`? You can further try `$("#addToCartBtn").on('click',function(){
  console.log("Hello");
});`. to check if it's a problem with clicking.